# Echoing the global variables in zsh

Tags: zsh, substitution

I've noticed that it's usual task to check global variables like PATH, GOPATH and etc. That's why I want to write small function so instead of typing a lot of letters

```
echo $PATH
```

I can type just

```
e PATH
```

The function itself should be very simple

```
function e() {
  echo $($1)   # it produces the error "command not found"
}
```

But the problem is how to substitute a variable to get the content of PATH?

P.S. I'm using zsh

Comment: @BenjaminW. .. under the circumstances, perhaps the dupe vote should be retracted.

Comment: @BenjaminW. in these duplications I didn't find any answer on my question

Comment: The bash tag should be removed then, because the dupes definitely answer the question for bash.

Comment: @BenjaminW. fixed

Comment: I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional (POSIX) notation to handle this uses the `eval` command, which many will warn you against:

```
e() {
  eval echo \"\$$1\"
}
```

In bash, however, you can use variable indirection:

```
function e() {
  printf '%s\n' "${!1}"
}
```

And in zsh, which you added as a tag after my initial answer, indirection is handled differently:

```
function e() {
  printf '%s\n' "${(P)1}"
}
```

This uses a *Parameter Expansion Flag* which you can read about in `man zshexpn`.

```
   P   This forces the value of the parameter name to be interpreted as a
       further parameter name, whose value will be used where  appropriate.
```

Comment: Second solution didn't work for me (bad substitution)

Comment: @megas, what version of bash are you using?  (You can `echo $BASH_VERSION` to see.)

Comment: I'm using zsh, version 5.3.

Comment: @megas, I've added a zsh solution as well.  Avoid `eval` if you can.